# Fluid scroll List with paging

Tags: pagination, paging, sapui5

I have a JSON Model like this:

```
[
{code:'01', descr:'descr 01'},
{code:'02', descr:'descr 02'},
{code:'03', descr:'descr 03'},
{code:'04', descr:'descr 04'},
{code:'05', descr:'descr 05'},
{code:'06', descr:'descr 06'},
{code:'07', descr:'descr 07'},
{code:'08', descr:'descr 08'},
{code:'09', descr:'descr 09'},
{code:'10', descr:'descr 10'}
]
```

I show the array in a List  https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.List.html

I use the list (in a Dialog, but this is not significant) to make the user choice the value to set in an Input field.
I don't use ODATA, but I use rest methods to retrieve the list. **I use a server-side pagination to retrieve blocks of data**; for example:

when  I open the list I call

```
getHints, {from:1, to 10}
```

The server send back the list with first 10 record and I show rightly their in the list.

Then I scroll the list and when I am at the end the event updateFinished is run and I call the next 10 records:

```
getHints, {from:11, to 20}
```

and the server send back

```
[
{code:'11', descr:'descr 11'},
{code:'12', descr:'descr 12'},
{code:'13', descr:'descr 13'},
{code:'14', descr:'descr 14'},
{code:'15', descr:'descr 15'},
{code:'16', descr:'descr 16'},
{code:'17', descr:'descr 17'},
{code:'18', descr:'descr 18'},
{code:'19', descr:'descr 19'},
{code:'20', descr:'descr 20'}
]
```

In the callback I push the record in the JSONModel and I have now 20 records in the list BUT I have a strange behavior:

***The scroll bar return to the top*** and in this mode the user does not have a fluid scroll.

How can I solve my strange problem?

PS.
I update my model in this mode:

```
var aElements=oModel.getProperty('/elements');

_.map(p_serverData.data.lookup, function (oElement) {
            var oHintElement = {};
            oHintElement.code = oElement.code;
            oHintElement.description = oElement.descr;
            aElements.push(oHintElement);
        });

oModel.setProperty('/elements', aElements);
```

Comment: There's a gotcha in your code. When you run `var aElements=oModel.getProperty('/elements');`, aElements doesn't contain a duplicate of the data in your model, but contains a reference. So your map/push operation is running directly on the data in your model. Try to clone the data, then run your operation, and then push the clone back into your model and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: you say `aElements doesn't contain a duplicate of the data in your model` but if I try `to clone the data` I exactly create a duplicate!

Comment: Your code doesn't show that you're cloning aElements. It shows that aElements is going to be a reference.